# Assign .vcproj files to Visual Studio 2008, when Visual Studio 2010 installed

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

I have encountered a strange error. I use Windows 7 x64. Visual Studio 2010 (VS10) and Visual Studio 2008 (VS08) are both installed. Now i want to make sure that when i doubleclick open a .vcproj file it is being opened by VS8 and not VS10. Now this seems like a trivial problem, but:
"righclick -> open with -> choose default program -> select devenv.exe of VS08 -> always open with" doesnt work. In fact after browsing for devenv.exe of VS08 it does not show up in the list/menue where it is supposed to be displayed.

This is very strange and annoying, maybe someone already encountered this error and know a solution.

Comment: Avoid tinkering with this.  This is handled by VSLauncher.exe, a program that looks at the .csproj file and automatically starts the correct version of VS.  Bypassing it just produces errors when VS2008 tries to open a VS2010 project.

Comment: Iam not working with c#. Its a c++ project file ".vcproj" and more than that, it is a vs2008 project file. The vs2010 project files are named differently ".vcxproj". Thats what makes this bug so annoying. Since after vs10 starts, it wants to run a converter, to convert to the new format, something i don't want.

Comment: The only repro I can get for that is when the .vcproj file was converted before.  The launcher will then start VS2010 instead of VS2008.  And indeed trigger the project converter again.  Sloppy, but the project can't be opened in VS2008 anymore.  Is there a .vcxproj in the same directory?

Comment: No there isnt. I mean right know i just start vs08 and open the vcproj file from there. But this is kind of annoying. I mean i don't really believe that it is not possible to assign .vcproj files to vs08 and .vcxproj files to vs10. There must be a way.

Comment: @Hans The problem is, it does NOT choose the correct version of VS. There is no rationale for not being able to bind .vsproj files to 2008 and .vsxproj files to 2010. If it's VSLauncher.exe that's giving us grief, I want it to butt out. I think I will try disabling it.

Comment: There is a conspiracy afoot. The file-type association dialog is in on it. It refuses to show VS 2008 as an option.

Comment: The VC++ 2008 Express installer is in on the conspiracy. VC++ 2008 Express is not even registered as an installed program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i finally found a way. You can use the application "[default programs editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/)" to mess with the standard file associations.

Comment: I tried that. The little app said it had changed the registry entry, but the file type was still bound to the wrong IDE. I am seriously suspecting that there is special case code in the OS to make people crazy. It insists that regardless of what I do, when I click on a .vcproj file it will open VC++ 2010 Express and offer to mangle the project file for me and then give me inscrutable warnings about how the nonsensical names it just invented do not make sense to it. And of course after it converts the project file to use the IDE I do not want, the project no longer works. @#$%^!!

Comment: Strange, it worked for me. What you also can do using this program is to add a context menue option to open with vs2008.

Answer (score 1):

I GOT IT! For the Express versions at least. I strongly suspect these instructions can be modified to apply to the full version. The names will change of course.

I spent a lot more time on this than I will ever save by being able to click through to the correct IDE, but darn it, I just hate to give up.

Here's the deal. Strangely, the associations seem to be keyed to the program file names. (Say, what?? That sure is the way it looks to me.) Both VC++ Express 2008 and 2010 are named VCExpress.exe. We'll give the 2008 version an alias. We'll also use a doppelganger to pull off something of a ruse.

1. Navigate to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE". Make a copy of VCExpress.exe, (not a shortcut), and re-name it VCExpress-2008.exe. (It would probably do just to re-name the original and use the new name in step 3.)
2. Open regedit.exe. Create a new key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\VSExpress-2008.exe
3. Edit the (default) value in that key, to hold the string "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\VCExpress.exe" [sic]
4. Go through the drill with the file-association dialog again. Right-click, open with, choose default program, yada, yada, yada. Browse your way down to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE and click on VSExpress-2008.exe.
5. VCExpress-2008 now shows up as a program in good standing, with its icon proudly displayed on the front page above the fold. (Don't tell the dialog, but you and I know it really points to VCExpress.exe, not the copy we made.) Click it.
6. Celebrate.